# Is there an event for checkbox changed state?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Is there an event for checkbox change when the state is changed/modified based on some other interaction. I mean not by clicking on the text box.

I've tried this code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('change',function(){
    alert('Checkbox state is changed.');
});
```

...but as you can see in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/wmVtB/), if I click the checkbox I see an alert showing "Checkbox state is changed." message triggered by the change event. But the same is not triggered when the checkbox state is changed using the button.

Am I missing anything?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're modifying the attribute "checked" in the `DOM` but the same event handler is not being called.

In your button event click you could use `trigger` and do:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('change');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wmVtB/7/

Answer (score 1):

No, setting the `checked` attribute via JavaScript does not fire any event. If you need to fire one, you would have to script it yourself or trigger a `click` event, which in turn does then fire the state change.